# How to set AKFrequencyTracker and AKSampler correctly

Tags: ios, audio, audiokit

I'm using AudioKit AKFrequencyTracker and AKSampler in my app to play piano sounds, and then I listen to the user's input from the mic. I made an example of how my AudioSingleton is defined.

```
    try? sampler_1.loadWav("Piano")

    let micCopy1 = AKBooster(mic)
    let micCopy2 = AKBooster(micCopy1)
    tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(micCopy2, hopSize: 200, peakCount: 2_000)
    let silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain: 0)

    if let inputs = AudioKit.inputDevices {
        try? AudioKit.setInputDevice(inputs[0])
        try? mic.setDevice(inputs[0])
    }

    let mixer = AKMixer(sampler_1, silence)


    AudioKit.output = mixer
    AudioKit.start()
```

Now the problem is the piano sound is playing in a low volume. When I'm trying to add the "defaultToSpeaker" setting, the sampler makes a strange feedback sound and a strange noise in the background, as if there's a reverb attached to it, but not in a good way.

```
    AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true
    AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
```

So, how can I keep playing this sound and listen to the tracker without hearing strange noises?
Note: I don't need to play and listen at the same time, I need to switch between them- first play the sound and then listen to the user's input.